# How to create a .so file on windows for C++ Library to be used in Python

Tags: python, c++, g++, cygwin

I use cygwin tools.
But when I compile a .cpp file and load the .so file in Python command line, I get this error message:

> OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.

But simple .dll files are loaded fine.

I think the fault is in Code or Compiling process. What do I need to write, something like export functions in .dll？

Just simple "hello world" is OK. Please give me a sample, and compile command too.

Comment: Do you use the Cygwin-provided Python interpreter, or the standard Windows Python? Because the standard Windows Python interpreter uses Windows, which uses DLL's and not Cygwin shared objects (.so).

Comment: Maybe standard Windows Python......Python3.4.3

Comment: How to check the version?